# 18.04 error "Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded" when booting

Tags: boot, 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. When I start error with `Started User Manager for UID 1000`, latest 10 minutes, restart it will show a black screen with this message: `Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded`.

[image]